# PowerBI - Return all rows 'Active' during selected month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to create a method to return any subscription record that was active in the month in question. Could anyone offer advice?

I have two tables

The typical date table for around 50 (don't know why!) years.
Date, Month, Year, Year-Month and so on.

Subscription Table

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 | 25/02/2023 |
| 2 | 20/02/2023 | 27/02/2023 |
| 3 | 28/02/2023 | 13/03/2023 |

At present date only joins to End Date (to meet other requirements).

The desire is to be able to filter the data on display to accurately show the number of active subscriptions within a month.

E.g:

If 2023-Jan is selected, it will only return 1 row within a visual.

If 2023-Feb is selected, it will display 3 rows within a visual.

Comment: https://www.daxpatterns.com/events-in-progress/

Comment: That's a great little blog offered by @DavideBacci.  I used to do this with a disconnected date table.  Making use of REMOVEFILTERS is a nice approach.

Comment: Making my way through this today/over the weekend. So far so good!